# Open Street maps query for ATM

Tags: web-services, openstreetmap

I'm trying to find a way to query Open Street Maps for a list of ATMs for a particular city, any ideas how to achieve this?

I know we can use mapquest to query for this information, but it needs a box and it gives me less informaton than Open Street Maps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you meant MapQuest's Nominatim instance. Just for the record: [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) is actually created by the OpenStreetMap community. MapQuest just runs it, too.

Querying for specific objects is best done by using the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). This API also has a nice frontend, [overpass turbo](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo). It makes creating queries and running them really easy and also includes a nice visualization of the result.

This query will retrieve all ATMs (which are tagged as [amenity=atm](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3aamenity=atm)) in Berlin:

```xml
<osm-script output="json" timeout="25">
  <!-- fetch area “berlin” to search in -->
  <id-query {{nominatimArea:berlin}} into="area"/>
  <!-- gather results -->
  <union>
    <!-- query part for: “atm” -->
    <query type="node">
      <has-kv k="amenity" v="atm"/>
      <area-query from="area"/>
    </query>
  </union>
  <!-- print results -->
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

You can view the [result on overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/3oN). This query has been automatically generated by overpass turbo, I just had to type "atm in Berlin" into it's [wizard](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Wizard).

Note that this is a special overpass turbo query which cannot be run directly via the Overpass API. overpass turbo adds some extra keywords like `{{nominatimArea:berlin}}` which will be automatically replaced by the bounding box of *Berlin* returned by *Nominatim*. But if you already know the bbox or want to retrieve it on your own using Nominatim, then you can specify it directly:

```xml
<osm-script output="json" timeout="25">
  <!-- gather results -->
  <union>
    <!-- query part for: “atm” -->
    <query type="node">
      <has-kv k="amenity" v="atm"/>
      <bbox-query e="13.92242431640625" n="52.67221863915279" s="52.32778621884898" w="12.992706298828125"/>
    </query>
  </union>
  <!-- print results -->
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

Both the Overpass API and overpass turbo support various output formats for the result, including XML and JSON.

Comment: scai, thank you for providing me such an answer. Good example and explanation.